# Assigning value to input manually does not effect 'ngForm.value' after submission in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular7

I'm using Angular and need to set the value of an input in my component using another component as a list picker inside a modal. I'm doing it like this:

```
showPartPicker(myInput: any) {
    const modalPartPicker = this.modalService.open(WarehousePartPickerComponent);
    modalPartPicker.componentInstance.emmiter
    .subscribe((selectedCode: WarehousePartGet) => {

        myInput.value = selectedCode.code; // <---- Here I'm assigning the value
        console.log(myInput);
    });
}
```

And this is part of my template:

```
<form #formData="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="formData.valid && submit(formData, cardIndex); this.debug.log(formData)" >
    ...

    <buttontype="button" (click)="showPartPicker(inputPart)"></button>
    <input ngModel #inputPart type="text" name="warehouse_part_code" required />

    ...
```

**The problem:** The value in the form changes successfully but does not affect *ngForm.value* after submission and it's still an empty string.
But if I type the value into the form, ngForm.value will be changed.

**Sample code:**

> https://angular-3csmet.stackblitz.io

Comment: Can you please create a minimum reproduction on stackblitz

Comment: @SachinGupta This is a sample: https://angular-3csmet.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you set value with `myInput.value = selectedCode.code;` you are changing value attribute of DOM Input element.

however, as explained in [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#description) ngForm directive creates and registers a FormGroup instance on form element. By using `ngModel` with a `name` attribute on input element, a FormControl is created as a child of FormGroup.

Consequently, if you want to programatically change the value of any element within the form it should be done using ReactiveForms API functions. Otherwise, changes in the DOM will not be reflected to underlying FormControl unless there is an explicit user interaction with the DOM.

Basically, if you want to change value of any form element programatically, you should do this on underlying FormControl, not on DOM. So changing signature of `showPartPicker` as follows should do the trick;

```
<button type="button" (click)="showPartPicker(formData.controls.warehouse_part_code)">
</button>
```

and

```
showPartPicker(formCtrl: AbstractControl) {
    const modalPartPicker = this.modalService.open(WarehousePartPickerComponent);
    modalPartPicker.componentInstance.emmiter
    .subscribe((selectedCode:WarehousePartGet) => {

        formCtrl.setValue(selectedCode.code);

    });
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but I always have this error in VS Code in the template: "Identifier 'warehouse_part_code' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member" How can I fix this?